# Automate like my facebook fan page from my site

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I am trying to automate like my facebook fan page from my site without clicking like button.
I tried
 `$('.pluginButtonLabel').click()` function. 
The click event fires but the like button does not get pressed. Please help.

Comment: What's your reason for doing so? It is not a good practice to have all of your visitors logged into Facebook like your page without their permission, and, if this is the case, you should not be doing this.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a major security concern and also a very dark UX design pattern. Your answer is: make your website content interesting enough that people want to share and learn from you and will "Like"  your content voluntarily.

Comment: side note: i just bumped your profile to 20.000 reputation, nice *fistbump*